# DateTime.Now gives me only date when I set it as object in database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, datetime, entity-framework-5

I am using `@DateTime.now` in my view to save current date but somehow I can't set current date AND hour to my object, it does not saves hours/minutes/seconds. It saves same data as `@DateTime.Today` whould show. It just saves as

> 2014-01-06 00:00:00

While date is current(correct) date and hour is set to zeroes.

Here is my model, not much to see, I don't see how it could be possibly wrong here.

```
public class Posts
    {
        ...
        public DateTime PostDate { get; set; }
        ...

    }
```

And here is how I put DateTime to my model in view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>

        [...]

        <input type="hidden" name="PostDate" value=@DateTime.Now/>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create"/>
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

When I call `@DateTime.Now` in view it shows me correct values.
I tried to convert it to string (By making object `PostDate` also string) but I was still getting the same issue.
What I am missing?

Comment: what is your column's data type in your database ?

Comment: Looks like your column type is `Date` instead of `DateTime`.

Comment: Please show us the **rendered** HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably acting weird because you didn't put quotes around your value attribute. Change to this.

```
<input type="hidden" name="PostDate" value="@DateTime.Now" />
```

as @JohnH suggests this works too

```
@Html.Hidden("PostDate",DateTime.Now)
```

Comment: Good spot.  That might be it, too.  Although, rather than just adding quotes, I'd suggest using `Html.HiddenFor` / `Html.Hidden` instead, as they'll generate the correct output without the fuss.

Answer (score 0):

When I encountered this problem, I realized it was because in the SQL, I had chosen "date" instead of "datetime" in the design of my table.  The database could not accept the time value because it was misconfigured.  Changing the table definition to accommodate the full "datetime."